# Laravel Eloquent when date condition

Tags: laravel

I have an eloquent query, and inside it I have 2 condition. The first is when `attendance_time == today` and second is `attendance_time == yesterday`. I want to use that condition but I don't know how.

I've tried like code bellow, but still not working.

```
Attendance::where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
      ->where('in_out', 'in')
      ->when('attendance_time' == Carbon::today(), function ($q) {
            return $q->where('attendance_time', Carbon::today());
      })->when('attendance_time' == Carbon::yesterday(), function ($q) {                  
            return $q->where('attendance_time', Carbon::yesterday());
      })->first();
```

Format for `attendance_time` is `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whereDate, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) is additional info. However, your query needs some improvement. If you use **when** it is like an if statement. It checks your condition and if it is true then add query inside of its function.

If you create something like that:

```
  Attendance::where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
      ->where('in_out', 'in')
      ->when($request->attendace_time, function ($q) {
          return $q->where('attendance_time', Carbon::today());
      })
```

That means if your request has attendace_time then add where query.

Or If you want to just filter todays attandees then you can use:

```
  Attendance::where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
      ->where('in_out', 'in')
      ->whereDate('attendance_time', Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereBetween` method:

```php
   use Carbon/Carbon;

   ...

   Attendance::where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
      ->where('in_out', 'in')
      ->whereBetween('attendance_time', [
          Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateString(),
          Carbon::now()->toDateString()
      ])->first();
```